# Migrate Plus custom module no longer working. Can't figure out why

Tags: migrations, 9

My module used to work flawlessly but recently something must've changed as it no longer works.
Below are my processes.

```
drush ms
 --------------------------------------------------- --------------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- ---------------------
  Group                                               Migration ID          Status   Total   Imported   Unprocessed   Last Imported
 --------------------------------------------------- --------------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- ---------------------
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_course_offerings)   paragraph_time        Idle     152     112        40            2022-04-08 08:58:44
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_course_offerings)   paragraph_schedule    Idle     152     112        40            2022-04-08 08:58:47
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_course_offerings)   paragraph_offering    Idle     152     110        42            2022-04-08 08:58:50
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_course_offerings)   content_ptco          Idle     117     69         46            2022-04-08 08:58:54
 
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_courses)            pt_course_image       Idle     327     5          321           2020-01-13 15:43:38
  Part-Time Course migrations (pt_courses)            pt_course_migration   Idle     327     323        4             2021-12-16 14:18:54
```

I get the following error when I run it within the group:

```
drush mim --group=pt_courses --sync
[warning] array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! EntityStorageBase.php:312

In MigrateToolsCommands.php line 983:
pt_course_image Migration - 352 failed.
```

I then rolled back and tried again and got the following:

```
drush mim --group=pt_courses --sync
 [warning] array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! EntityStorageBase.php:312
   1/327 [>---------------------------]   0% [notice] The file public://migrated/image1.svg was not deleted because it does not exist.
 [notice] The file public://migrated/image2.png was not deleted because it does not exist.
 [notice] The file public://migrated/image3.jpg was not deleted because it does not exist.
 [notice] The file public://migrated/image4.png was not deleted because it does not exist.
 [notice] The file public://migrated/image5.svg was not deleted because it does not exist.
 [notice] Rolled back 6 items - done with 'pt_course_image'
 [notice] Processed 326 items (0 created, 0 updated, 326 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'pt_course_image'

In MigrateToolsCommands.php line 983:

  pt_course_image Migration - 326 failed.
```

If I just run the image import portion, I just get this:

```
drush mim pt_course_image --sync

In MigrateToolsCommands.php line 983:
pt_course_image Migration - 352 failed.
```

Can anyone let me know if they see an error in my code?

migrate_plus.migration.pt_course_image.yml file is as follows:

```
# Migration file for creating "image" for part-time courses.
#
# Detailed explanations for various elements of a migration
# YAML have been provided in migrate_plus.migration.pt_course_migration.yml

id: pt_course_image
label: Image associated with part-time programs.
migration_group: pt_courses
migration_tags:
  - part-time course
  - file
  - image
# Source.
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://import/pt-courses.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    [image_file]
  fields:
    8:
      name: image_file
      label: 'Course Logo/Image'
  constants:
    file_source_uri: public://import
    file_dest_uri: 'public://migrated'
# Destination.
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
# Mappings.
process:
  file_source:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: image_file
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_source_uri
        - image_file
  file_dest:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_dest_uri
        - image_file
  filename: image_file
  uri:
    -
      plugin: file_copy
      source:
        - '@file_source'
        - '@file_dest'
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_pt_courses
```

The code for the migrate_plus.migration.pt_course_migration.yml file is below:

```
# Migration file for creating "part-time course" nodes from CSV.
id: pt_course_migration
label: Part-Time Course Migration
description: Migrate part-time courses from a CSV generated file.
migration_group: pt_courses
migration_tags:
  - CSV
  - part-time program
source:
  plugin: csv

  path: 'public://import/pt-courses.csv'

  header_row_count: 1

  # Unique ID.
  ids:
    [course_code]
  fields:
    0:
      name: course_code
      label: 'Course Code'
    1:
      name: title
      label: 'Course Title'
    2:
      name: category
      label: 'Course Category'
    3:
      name: area
      label: "Area of Interest"
    4:
      name: description
      label: 'Course Description'
    5:
      name: additional
      label: 'Additional Information'
    6:
      name: credit
      label: 'Course Credits'
    7:
      name: new
      label: 'New Course'
    8:
      name: image_file
      label: 'Course Logo/Image'
    9:
      name: image_alt
      label: 'Image Alt Text'

  # Assign hard-coded values to certain properties using constants.
  constants:
    uid_root: 1
    bool_0: 0
    bool_1: 1
    basic_html: basic_html

# Destination
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: course_part_time

# Mapping.
process:
  # Define a default user for the imported nodes.
  uid: constants/uid_root
  # Define the content type to use
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: course_part_time
  # Define the fields
  field_new_course:
    plugin: default_value
    source: new
    default_value: constants/bool_0
  field_course_code: course_code
  title: title
  field_course_category:
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: category
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    bundle_key: vid
    bundle: part_time_category
    value_key: name
    ignore_case: true
  field_course_credits: credit
  'body/value': description
  'body/format': constants/basic_html
  'field_course_additional_info/value': additional
  'field_course_additional_info/format': constants/basic_html
  field_area_of_interest:
    -
      plugin: explode
      delimiter: ', '
      source: area
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: part_time_areas_of_interest
      value_key: name
      ignore_case: true
  'field_course_image/target_id':
    plugin: migration_lookup
    migration: pt_course_image
    source: image_file
  'field_course_image/alt': image_alt

migration_dependencies:
  optional:
    - pt_course_image

dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_pt_courses
```

Does anyone have any ideas to help me out here? I can't seem to figure out why it keeps failing on me.

**EDIT**
When I run `drush migrate:messages pt_course_image` I get the following (I've edited to show an example as it lists all 350+ rows that I have in my csv file):

```
Source ID(s)         Destination ID(s)   Level   Message                                                                                 
 -------------------- ------------------- ------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ABC 123                                 1       pt_course_image:uri:file_copy: File 'public://import/ABC 123' does not exist           
  DEF 456                                 1       pt_course_image:uri:file_copy: File 'public://import/DEF 456' does not exist           
  GHI 789                                 1       pt_course_image:uri:file_copy: File 'public://import/GHI 789' does not exist
```

Comment: what do you see with [drush migrate:messages](https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/migrate_messages/)

Comment: @sonfd I've added what happens when I run the command to the bottom of the main post. Any idea on how to correct this?

Comment: That's your error message - the source file doesn't exist when the file_copy plugin tries to copy the file.

Comment: The file it should be reading from is `path: 'public://import/pt-courses.csv'` and grabbing the file location from the `8` column. What it seems to be saying is that it's looking for a file at `public://import/ABC 123`, however, that `ABC 123` would be the data in the first column of the csv file.